# Explanation of the Hebrew word אֲשֶׁר

Tags: hebrew

I checked up the BDB lexicon and some softwares to study the usage of the word אֲשֶׁר in Bible. However in my level its seem so complex and I am unable to understand properly. Can anyone please tell me in simple words how and when this word "אֲשֶׁר" is used in Biblical Hebrew?

Comment: Why is this important to you?

Comment: @Mac'sMusings That is a link to אָשֵׁר the son of Jacob. אֲשֶׁר the relative particle is [here](https://biblehub.com/hebrew/strongs_834.htm)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This word simply is the equivalent of the relative pronoun in English—it means "which" if referring to an object, place, or thing, and "who" if referring to a person. It simply serves to **identify or describe** the person **by something which characterizes them.**

So, for example, Genesis 3:17:

> And He said to Adam: Because you have harkened to the voice of your wife, and have eaten of the tree **about which [אשר]** *I gave you instruction*, saying that you shall not eat of it, the ground shall be cursed for your sake: you shall eat of it in grief all the days of your life.

Here it serves to specify the tree: this is the tree of the knowledge of good and evil, about which God gave instruction ("You shall not eat of it").

Again, Genesis 1:7:

> And God made the expanse, and separated the waters **that were [אשר]** *under the expanse*, from **those [אשר]** *above the expanse*: and it was so.

Even though the letters א, ש, and ר are used in other words and names, it should not be confused for this word.

Comment: Good. Feel free to incorporate my second comment under Lowther's answer -- it's almost but not quite equivalent to the English relative pronoun.

Comment: Would it be safe to call those anomalous cases, do you think?

Comment: Hmm, probably yes. At a minimum, they stood out to me as odd on reading!

Comment: That is because you are using an Indo-European mindset.

Comment: I think he meant relative to its normative usage, not another language or culture (namely his own).

Comment: Indeed, I meant compared to most times I read this word in the Bible. By the way, my reading this morning reminded me of another use: [Ex. 29:38](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Exodus%2029%3A38-46&version=NIV;WLC): וְזֶה אֲשֶׁר תַּעֲשֶׂה עַל־הַמִּזְבֵּחַ "This is what you will do [=offer] on the altar." Here אֲשֶׁר is not just "which" but "that which".

Comment: That use reminds me of [Ex. 3:14](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Exodus+3%3A14-15&version=NIV;WLC): אֶהְיֶה אֲשֶׁר אֶהְיֶה "I am what/who I am" — incidentally a clue as to why the OP might be interested in the word. (For more on how to place the copula in that line, see [this answer](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/34107).)

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something, this is in the BDB and should answer your Question?

H834
אשׁר
'ăsher
BDB Definition:
1) (relative participle)
1a) which, who
1b) that which
2) (conjunction)
2a) that (in object clause)
2b) when
2c) since
2d) as
2e) conditional if
Part of Speech: relative particle
conjunction
A Related Word by BDB/Strong’s Number: a primitive relative pronoun (of every gender and number)

Furthermore, you can see the first citation of אשׁר in:

Gen 1:7  ויעשׂ אלהים את־הרקיע ויבדל בין המים **אשׁר** מתחת לרקיע ובין המים **אשׁר** מעל לרקיע ויהי־כן׃

KJV Gen 1:7  And God made the firmament, and divided the waters **which** were under the firmament from the waters **which** were above the firmament: and it was so.

אשׁר is a general part of Hebrew speech, nothing to in-depth.

Comment: One linguistically interesting note on *asher* is that in some sentences, especially in the books of 1 & 2 Kings, its syntax is a little different: even though it appears to be a relative pronoun, sometimes it's followed by a second pronoun for the same antecedent! A word-by-word gloss of [1 Kings 13:17](https://biblehub.com/interlinear/1_kings/13-17.htm) reads: "Return by going on the road which (*asher*) you came by **it**." This last word would be omitted in English, and interestingly, Elijah himself omits it a few verses earlier in [13:9](https://biblehub.com/interlinear/1_kings/13-9.htm).

Comment: I did redact my statement above concerning "particular grammatical form " as the question did have vowel pointing which I did not notice, so I had removed the portion which stared the misunderstanding of @Luke Sawczak . Thanks

Comment: Works for me. Comments removed.